# MIT APPInventor error on openning. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, java, php, android

I installed MIT AppInventor successfully, but when I tried to open it on this address `localhost:8004/`
 It shows an error like this: `Sorry, the requested URL 'http://127.0.0.1:8004/' caused an error: Not Found: '/'`

Here's the aiStarter lookslike when I visit the url:
 [image: aiStarter after visiting the address]

I am running a 64bit version of windows. And the appinvertor installed on Program Files(x86). How to fix this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check using this;
1. http://127.0.0.1:8004/ping/ or,
2. http://localhost:8004/ping/ to test the system is OK or not.

Emulator Check:
1. http://localhost:8004/start/

Other Codes;
1. http://localhost:8004/reset/ - This resets the emulator.
2. http://localhost:8004/echeck/ - The device and emulator status.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you want to use this address instead:
localhost:8888